# MySQL Slow Query - Range and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a simple query which selects a specific time range of data then group by.
The SQL looks like:

```
SELECT
    C,
    sum(X),
    sum(Y) 
FROM
    table
WHERE
    A = ${id} AND
    B BETWEEN '2021-08-01'AND '2021-08-02'
GROUP BY
    C;
```

B's data type is `date`.
C's data type is `varchar`.
X, Y's data type is `bigint`.
The `index` is (A, B, C).

When I use `EXPLAIN`, in the `extra` column: `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`. `Key` column: (A, B, C).

I guess the `index` stops at `B`, since `B` is a range condition.

Is there any other way to optimize this query? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please see the section about performance questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question and edit your question

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: If `B` is a DATE, that is 2 days; if it is `DATETIME`, that is 1 day plus one second (an extra midnight).

Answer (score 0):

The columns, in optimal order for the `INDEX`, are

```
A -- Column(s) being tested in WHERE with =
B -- One column in WHERE as a range
No more columns are worth adding to the INDEX
```

Exception:  If *all* the columns used *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are in the index, then the index is "covering".  This gives a slight performance boost because it won't have to bounce between the INDEX's BTree and the data's BTree.

```
INDEX(A, B,  -- first, and in this order (as above)
      C, X, Y)  -- in any order
```

I doubt if the "covering" index is worth using *in that query*.

Another *possibility*

```
A -- all the = columns
C -- the GROUP BY columns
```

This would avoid the sorting that *may* be necessary for `GROUP BY`.  So...

```
INDEX(A, C), or
INDEX(A, C, B, X, Y)  -- covering
```

I'm surprised that your `EXPLAIN` said "Using index".  That means that the index is covering, yet your `(A,B,C)` is not.

More on building the optimal index:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Another technique...  Often SUMs (and COUNTs) like that come along with "Data Warehouse" schemas.  A very good speedup is to build and maintain a Summary table of, say, hourly subtotals.  Then, the `SELECT` SUMs the subtotals to get the total.  More discussion in [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

"Using filesort" may actually happen in RAM.  (Don't be put off by "file".)